# SQL missing right parenthesis ORA-00907

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error? Thank you!

```
    CREATE TABLE Booking (
  hotelNo char(2)   NOT NULL,
  guestNo char(2)   NOT NULL,
  dateFrom date     NOT NULL,
  dateTo date    
  roomNo char(2)  NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT booking_pk PRIMARY KEY (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom),
  CONSTRAINT booking_hotel_fk FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo) REFERENCES 
  CONSTRAINT booking_guest_fk FOREIGN KEY (guestNo) REFERENCES Guest(guestNo),
  CONSTRAINT booking_room_fk FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo, roomNo) 
  REFERENCES Room(hotelNo, roomNo)
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two errors.  The missing comma after `date`.  But you are also not completing the foreign key references.  So, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Booking (
  hotelNo char(2)   NOT NULL,
  guestNo char(2)   NOT NULL,
  dateFrom date     NOT NULL,
  dateTo date, 
  -----------^  
  roomNo char(2)  NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT booking_pk PRIMARY KEY (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom),
  CONSTRAINT booking_hotel_fk FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo) REFERENCES hotel(hotelNo),
  -------------------------------------------------------------^
  CONSTRAINT booking_guest_fk FOREIGN KEY (guestNo) REFERENCES Guest(guestNo),
  CONSTRAINT booking_room_fk FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo, roomNo) REFERENCES Room(hotelNo, roomNo)
  );
```

Comment: I missed it `hotel(hotelNo)` :P

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try it soon, SQLFiddle just went down right now :-(